# passing function from server to client component Next 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

According to the Next.js [docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fundamentals) for the app directory:

"Whenever possible, we recommend fetching data inside Server Components. Server Components always fetch data on the server."

This is great because I am hitting an external API (where I cannot change the CORS policy - Allow-Origins...).

I have a page (server component) with a form (client component), and I am trying to hit the API using the server component.

Home page

```
import Form from './Form';

export default function Home() {
   handleSubmit = () => {...submit logic}
   return <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
}
```

Form Component

```
'use client'

export default function Form({ onSubmit }) {
 return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>...</form>
}
```

When I try to pass the `handleSubmit` function to the client component, I get this error:

```
Functions cannot be passed directly to Client Components because they're not serializable.
```

1. I'm not sure what that means.
2. Is there a way to pass functions to client components?
3. I need to fetch from a server component because the API has CORS policy. Is it possible to do what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any `error.js` in your directory?
Add `use client` at the top of the file.

See reference here:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42408
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have added 'use client' and it works like a magic!

Answer (score 4):

do it in your home:

```
import Form from './Form';

handleSubmit = () => {
   'use server';

   ...submit logic
}

export default function Home() {
   return <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass a function from a server component to a client component.

> Props passed from the Server to Client Components need to be serializable. This means that values such as **functions**, Dates, etc, **cannot** be passed directly to Client Components.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

Though it is true that data fetching is recommended to be done on the server side, passing a function that is written in a server side file to a client component does **not** help. **It is still to be run in the client component.**

To fetch data on the server side, **do it in a server component, instead of just a server function**. Then **pass any data necessary, not functions** to a client component. This design is why the data passed from server component to client component must be serializable (like the returning data from an API end point). Do not pass a function from server component to client component.

In your case, however, there is no need to fetch on the server side, because data flow with authentication is two-direction—you need to pass username and password to the server and also update the client-side status (e.g. login context) when successfully authenticated. *Doing the data fetching on the server side in-between the two directions could be really hard, because the two data flows are both crossing the border.* **I suggest you just do it in the client component.**

Answer (score 2):

This is my first answer here so if you couldn't understand feel free to ask me as many questions as you can.

I was making a NextJS project as well and I was struggling with the same issue.

Turns out that the next team released a feature called serverActions that you can check in the docs here https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/forms-and-mutations#server-only-forms

But basicaly what you need to do is create the handleSubmit inside the client component and call another function, this one will be marked as 'use server'.

```
'use server'

export default function serverAction(){
  //do some stuff
}
```

```
'use client'

export default function ClientComponent() {
  async function handleSubmit() {
    serverAction()
  }
}
```

For this to work you'll need to add the config bellow to your next.config.js

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    serverActions: true,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message may be a little confusing. The solution may not be to add `"use server"` to the function.  In my case the component that called the function (the child component) and the component passing the function down (the parent component) were both on the client side - so the solution was actually to add `"use client"` to the parent.

Comment: Yes, the child components which have parents already tagged with `"use client"` do not need to have the `"use client"` even if they use hooks...

Answer (score 0):

> 3. I need to fetch from a server component because the API has a CORS policy. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

The CORS policy applies to any incoming request (whether the request comes from a front or server component doesn't matter).

What is the HTTP method you are going to use in your function? If it's POST, PUT or DELETE, you don't absolutely need to do it in a server component (the purpose of a server component is to optimize SEO by sending the data already loaded - it is called server-side rendering).

If this is a GET, what are you trying to accomplish? Dynamically load data based on what the user has chosen to fill in?

If so, I think it's easier to do this on the client side. Otherwise you don't need a form.